# How to send a message to the bot developer(me) via a command?

Tags: discord.py

I want to create a command in discord.py that sends me a dm with a suggestion attached to it. Or it should post the request in my discord log channel. Unfortunatly i have absolutly no clue how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a message to a specific channel:

```
await bot.send_message(discord.Object(id='INSERT CHANNEL ID HERE'), 'INSERT MESSAGE CONTENT HERE')
```

To send a direct message to yourself:

```
user = await bot.get_user_info('INSERT YOUR ID HERE')
await bot.send_message(user, 'INSERT MESSAGE CONTENT HERE')
```